# First response from API not updating error message Vue Axios

Tags: vue.js, axios

I am having trouble displaying error responses to on the first submit click.

The error messages pops up but only after the submit button is clicked twice. The response 400 is definitely created on the first click. With the second triggering the correct message.

```html
<div class="danger-alert" v-html="error" />
```

This is the Scripts:

```js
 export default {
    name: 'register',
    data() {
      return {
        model: {
          username: '',
          email: '',
          password: '',
          agree: false,
        }
      }
    },
    methods: {
      async onSubmit() {
        try {
          const response = await AuthenticationService.register({
            username: this.model.username,
            email: this.model.email,
            password: this.model.password,
            agree: this.model.agree
          })

          this.$router.push('/login')
        
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error)
          this.error = error.response.data.error
        }
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

```js
async register (req, res) {
    try {
      const user = await User.create(req.body)
      const userJson = user.toJSON()
      res.send({
        user: userJson,
        // token: jwtSignUser(userJson)
      })
      // res.send('Sign Up successfully')
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
      res.status(400).send({
        error: 'This account is already in use.'
      })
    }
  }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you show network request logs from developer tools in browser? ('Network' tab or the like)

Comment: @trainoasis added in description

Comment: What was the 1st request's response and was it a POST also? or OPTIONS?

Comment: @trainoasis POST and reponse was 400 duplicate (which is correct) but its not updating the Front End on the first response...

Comment: @trainoasis added the post for context

Comment: Does not seem it's 400 since it's not red in network requests list hm? Also if 400 are you sure your server is reachable and you are requesting the correct url? I would check using GET request first via browser for example. And debug using Postman or something alike - until you get a basic response like this, I would not dig into server code just yet

Comment: Try adding `error: null` or `error: ""` to your `data` properties. Vue likes to know about everything up-front

Comment: @Phil so im getting the correct response but its not updating on the UI correctly. Does it look like the error message would update with the response? Or am i missing a connection between the API and Vue? Any ideas. Cheers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. The error handling needs to be outside the data.model.

```
export default {
    name: 'register',
    data() {
      return {
        model: {
          username: '',
          email: '',
          password: '',
          agree: false,
        },
        error: null
      }
    },
    methods: {
      async onSubmit() {
        try {
          const response = await AuthenticationService.register({
            username: this.model.username,
            email: this.model.email,
            password: this.model.password,
            agree: this.model.agree
          })

          this.$router.push('/login')
        
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error.response.data.error)
          this.error = error.response.data.error
        }
      }
    }
```